# EXTJS - Submit form and display value in Grid

Tags: extjs

I am very new to EXTJS. Working on application with Form and Grid.

Form will have Browse (to upload docs), Combobox, textarea and Datefield. On submit, Progress bar have to appear to show progress of upload.

Document path, combobox field value, Text area value & Date value entered have to display in Grid. Delete button have to their by default in grid of each row, once value appeared.

I tried to submit form with POST method and output as JSON format. I can get value of other fields except **Filefield**. **How to get filefield value???**

Thanks

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('Docinfo').getForm();
if(form.isValid())
{
  var record = form.getValues();
  var output_json = {"header": Ext.JSON.encode(record)};
  Ext.Ajax.request({
  url:'data/CSApp.json',
  waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
  method: 'POST',
  jsonData: output_json,
  success: function(response) {
  Ext.Msg.alert('Data submitted');
  Ext.getCmp('Docinfo').getForm().reset();
  },
  failure: function(response) {
  Ext.Msg.alert('Error while submitting data');
  },
  headers: {'Content-Type' : 'text/html' , 'Accept' : 'application/json'}
  });
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all fileinput cannot be submitted via AJAX. Docs clearly describe this: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

Second, why are you using Ajax request to submit the form values instead of the Form submit function itself?

Comment: Hi dbrin, Thanks for your reply. As per my client request, i have to use AJAX method. If Filefield doesnt support this, No other way i can go with Form submit method to post a value. But, still with form submit, i cant able to get value to store inside my DB. I m getting JSON Error    

"You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <br>
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: documentcat in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\saveform\save-form.php</b> on line <b>6</b>"